# Automatically scroll down a table using google chart

Tags: javascript, scroll, google-visualization

Instead of having the whole window that scrolled (found on the web):

```
function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}
```

than in the HTML code

```
<body onLoad="pageScroll()">
```

,

I would rather want only my table to jump/scroll down until the last row.

Do I need to create a new method for the google table?

Thx

Answer (score 3):

If your table has a fixed height set in options and is large enough to enable scrolling, then you need to do something similar to scroll the scrollable portion of the table:

```
var myTable = new google.visualization.Table(document.querySelector('#table_div'));

function scrollTable () {
    var el = document.querySelector('#table_div > div > div:first-child');
    if (el) {
        el.scrollTop = el.scrollTop + 50;
        if (el.scrollTop + el.offsetHeight < el.scrollHeight) {
            setTimeout(scrollTable, 100);
        }
    }
}

google.visualization.events.addListener(myTable, 'ready', scrollTable);

myTable.draw(data, options);
```